# cov-emit process hangs and Coverity build never completes

Tags: coverity

I need to exclude a C++ source file from coverity build. This file is called `XMLHelperUtil.cpp` and is part of one of the many C++ projects included in the solution that I'm building. I tried adding it to the XML configuration file but without any success.

I did the following:

**(1)** Created a config file with the command:

```
cov-configure --config e:\temp\my_config.xml --msvc --xml-option=skip_file:"XMLHelperUtil.cpp"
```

This creates a series of templates for `msvc` that includes the following `skip_file` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE coverity SYSTEM "coverity_config.dtd">
<coverity>
<!-- THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED - YOU MAY ADD XML ENTITIES -->
<!-- TO UPDATE THE COMPILER CONFIGURATION AFTER THE begin_command_line_config CLOSING TAG. -->
    <cit_version>1</cit_version>
    <config>
      <build>
        <compiler>
          <template_compiler>true</template_compiler>
          <comp_name>devenv</comp_name>
          <comp_translator>msvc_devenv</comp_translator>
          <comp_lang>C</comp_lang>
          <comp_generic>msvc</comp_generic>
        </compiler>
        <options>
          <id>msvc_devenv-devenv-.*</id>
          <opt_preinclude_file>$CONFIGDIR$/../user_nodefs.h</opt_preinclude_file>
          <begin_command_line_config></begin_command_line_config>
          <skip_file>XMLHelperUtil.cpp</skip_file>
        </options>
      </build>
    </config>
    <md5>e471f73f8137b3bb42fd78a4695ff14f</md5>
</coverity>
```

**(2)** Built the project with the following command:

```
cov-build --config e:\temp\my_config.xml 
          --dir "E:\cov-int-out" 
          "d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild" 
          "<path>\mysolution.sln" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

The file is not skipped. What am I doing wrong?

References:

- https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Exclude-Unwanted-Files-from-Coverity-Scan-and-Manage-Unwanted-Issues-in-CIM
- https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Exclude-folders-from-Coverity-Scan-Analysis
- https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/cli-integration-cheatsheet

**UPDATE**
Reading the build_log.txt file, I can see that the file is actually skipped:

```
[STATUS] Ignoring file XMLHelperUtil.cpp because file "<path>\XMLHelperUtil.cpp" matches skip_file pattern "XMLHelperUtil"
```

I can see that it continues with other files and the it stops here:

```
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> "FilePath.cpp": using precompiled header file "E:\cov-int\emit\pch\__coverity_ms_pch__1"
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> "..\PtrRefCtr_.h", line 290: warning #1087: the object has type
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>           qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>           "CPtrRefCtrBase::Validate"
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>             object type is: const CPtrRefCtrBase
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>               Validate();
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>               ^
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> "..\PtrRefCtr_.h", line 383: warning #442: argument list for class
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>           template "CRefCtrAuto" is missing
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>            CRefCtrCom( Pointee *pObj ): CRefCtrAuto(pObj) { (this)->AddRef(); }
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>                                         ^
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> catastrophic signal: C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> tried to read from addr 0x0000000000000064
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> call stack backtrace:
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> cov-emit.exe mingw64 2021.9.0
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000f7f3e0
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004b2167
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000f7f39d
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000f7f6fb
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> KERNELBASE.dll mingw64 2021.9.0
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000001800e1922
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> ntdll.dll mingw64 2021.9.0
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00007ff8dc0eec73
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00007ff8dc0d18b6
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00007ff8dc0e2f3d
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00007ff8dc0a4557
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00007ff8dc0e20ca
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> cov-emit.exe mingw64 2021.9.0
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004b2167
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004f880f
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000515463
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000515bb4
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004d77d1
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004f87d8
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004f90ba
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000560fa0
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x000000000050f98b
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x000000000050fb25
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000005110c6
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000561308
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000005154f3
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000515aa5
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004c0dfd
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004f89d0
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000515463
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000515998
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004cee81
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004f85ff
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000515463
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000515aa5
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004cee81
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004f85ff
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004f90ba
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000560fa0
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x000000000051085a
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000699690
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000006aa44c
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000633fbd
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000635511
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x000000000063629e
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000638096
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000638a7f
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000006390ce
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004f06d5
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000673f02
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000006724fa
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x000000000053d079
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x000000000053e51b
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004949ae
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x000000000048e405
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x000000000048e9fe
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x0000000000490e5e
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x00000000004928c3
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> (last 4 repeated 2 more times)
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|>   0x000000000048e405
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> 
..|cov-translate|5052|output|> WARNING: cov-emit returned with code 4 for FilePath.cpp
```

Nothing happens after this. There are many `cov-emit` processes running:

[image]

If I start killing one process at a time, at some point it restarts. I see new things coming up in the log. There is no new output in the console though, and after processing a few files it stops in the same manner.

Comment: `skip_file` should work for this purpose; it's not obvious to me why it isn't working here.  Would you add your `build.log` file (written by `cov-build` to the intermediate directory) to your post?  That might contain a clue.  To get a complete log file, use Task Manager to kill the hung `cov-emit` (although a partial log file would still be useful).

Comment: This was helpful to figure out that the file is skipped and the error is totally different. Please see the updated section of my question above.

Comment: From the log file we can see that `cov-emit` definitely crashed at least once, and you're saying it is hanging multiple times too.  Those problems are likely beyond what's feasible to diagnose or fix over this forum.  (Unless maybe your binaries are corrupted?)  I think you'll have to open a support ticket with Synopsys.

Comment: I just realized that the problems actually started after I upgraded from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022. The problem could be MSBuild or Coverity's interaction with it. I'm running version 2021.09 and there is a newer version available. I'll install that one and see whether it behaves the same or not.

Comment: I installed version 2021.12.1 and it's the same problem. I get hundreds of `catastrophic signal: C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)`. The only change that seems to occur is that after such a crash a new `cov-emit` process is spawned and the build continues. I will try to take it with Synopsys.

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Synopsys support (https://community.synopsys.com/s/case/5002H00001OYqCTQA1/covemit-hangs-all-the-time) it was confirmed that the problem for the hangs is Coverity's current lack of support for Visual Studio 2022, which will come at some point in 2022.

Comment: With the question now focused on Coverity support for VS 2022, I've deleted my other answer.  Also, the question could be improved by mentioning VS 2022 in the title, and by specifying in the body which Coverity version you are using (I'm aware you said 2021.12.1 in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the non-intended file before cov-analyze stage. Delete the tu emit file from the idir using emit command. Based on the tu deletion, you will not analyze this file at cov-analyze stage and commit issues to server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).